# How to keep a hidden div shown?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, show-hide, hidden

I have this peice of jquery for radio boxes where I say if a radio box belonging to this class and with this id is clicked, show this hidden div. The problem is, when you refresh the pag the radio box is still clicked but the hidden div does not show. It only shows if I click a different radio box and then click back to the original radio box that was clicked.

This is the javascript I am using:

```
$(function(){     
    $('.display').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "rows"){
            $('.section').show();
        } else {
            $('.section').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

The following is an example that I got this piece of javascript from, to show you a working example. [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ivozo5/1/edit)

Now if this was a form, and you clicked offer 2 and then saved the form and came back to the page, that hidden div would not be shown. How do I get it to show the div as long as that radio box is clicked at all times?

**Note:** the example uses jquery 1.5.1, I am using the latest version of jquery.

It should be noted that how the radio box is being saved does not matter, The radio box user selection is saved and thus on a page refresh the radio box the user selected is "selected" still. The hidden div should then be shown - how ever is not.

It is only shown if I select a different radio box and then go back to the radio box that was originally selected. Please see the working example above to understand how the hidden div is shown when you select a radio box.

**I want this div to always be shown if the radio box is selected.**

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to save the user's selection using JavaScript?  When I refresh the page the radio doesn't stay selected.

Comment: How will the radio be selected after page refresh? Are you storing it on server and sending it back? Are you storing that information in local storage/cookie?

Comment: Added more information. please see OP.

Comment: " on a page refresh the radio box the user selected is "selected" still" this is that part of code the most important i think.

Comment: "It should be noted that how the radio box is being saved does not matter" --> In this case, why don't you add $('.section').show(); wherever you are selecting the radio box (manually) on page load?

Comment: Check for a clicked radio button on page load, then simulate a click if it is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){     

    // your function
    $('.display').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("id") === "rows"){
            $('.section').show();
        } else {
            $('.section').hide();
        }
    });

    // initial check
    if ($('input:radio:checked').attr('id') === "rows") {
        $('.section').show();
    }

});
```

You will need to add an identifier to the jQuery selector if you have more than one set of radio buttons on the page. You could use the input field's name like so:

```
$('input[name=myradiobutton]:radio:checked')
```

Comment: problem with this, name is always something like: name[value];

Comment: All your radio button inputs (for this grouping) should have the same name attribute. For example if you have a radio selection for cars the option name would be `name="car"` for each input field. But the value would be different for each, `value="ferrarri"`, `value="porsche"`, `value="laborghini"`, etc.